# when django invoking java, why utf-8 chars outputing is not ok?

Tags: java, python, linux, encoding

When I use django, I write a method can be invoked by http:// myhost/XXX/testIndex

```
def testIndex(request):
    res = os.system('java -jar test.HelloWorld' > /tmp/log)
    ... ...
```

and the HelloWorld java is as follows:

```
    public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("hello!");
        System.out.println("你好!");
}
```

When I access the http:// myhost/XXX/testIndex, the result is when I open the /tmp/log file, the UTF-8 chars is not correct!
like this

```
hello! ??!
```

What happened ? BTW, I am under linux centOS

Comment: What makes you think this writes UTF8 characters to the file? You're not setting any encoding anywhere.

Comment: When I use the shell, everything is ok, all my envionment is set UTF-8, my linux' locale, all my python and java files, also the python file is commented by #coding:utf-8, where should I put the encoding correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You have put non-ASCII characters in your Java source. This is not generally considered good practice, because you will need to tell the Java compiler what encoding you have used for the source file. If it's UTF-8, try: `javac -encoding UTF-8 HelloWorld.java`.
2. The default encoding for System.out may not be UTF-8. It would help if you said which JRE you are using, as different implementations may behave slightly differently. You may be able specify the encoding explicitly with `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`, although this is also [not recommended](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4163515). If it's the Sun or OpenJDK JRE, you need to set the LANG environment variable before Java starts; you might do this in your webserver configuration, or by using the `subprocess` python module which allows you to specify the environment passed to the new process.

Comment: 1. My environment variable LANG has been set to zh_CN.UTF-8

2. javac -encoding UTF-8 does not help, event if I do not put non-ASCII character in java source instead of reading UTF-8 encoded file and then print them, it also does not works, Why?

Comment: And another keypoint is that it works in the shell, only wrong in the drango service

Comment: Ok, so you've eliminated problem 1 and not problem 2. Most likely LANG is not set in the webserver environment.